# (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR when calling current_user.games

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model, console, associations

I'm trying to call `current_user.games` and keep getting the error:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column assignments.user_id does not exist)
LINE 1: ..." ON "games"."id" = "assignments"."game_id" WHERE "assignmen...

I believe my models are set up right to handle such a query but something tells me I have to run a migration that adds users as a reference?

Models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :invitable, invite_for: 2.weeks

  has_many :assignments
  has_many :games, through: :assignments
end
```

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :assignment, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :users, through: :assignment

    after_save :create_assignment

    def create_assignment
        Assignment.create(game_id: id)
    end
end
```

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :game
    belongs_to :user

    # belongs_to :assignor, class_name: "User", optional: true

    belongs_to :center_referee, class_name: 'User', optional: true
    belongs_to :assistant_referee_1, class_name: 'User', optional: true
    belongs_to :assistant_referee_2, class_name: 'User', optional: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :game    
end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "game_id"
    t.integer "center_referee_id"
    t.integer "assistant_referee_1_id"
    t.integer "assistant_referee_2_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "games", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "home_team"
    t.string "away_team"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "role"
  end
```

Comment: The assignments table needs a foreign key reference to the users table.

Comment: So that would just be a simple migration of ```rails g migration AddForeignKeyToAssignments users:reference```?

Comment: That's not pretty much the case. Adding the foreign key is not necessary. Instead, you may need to use a single inheritance table. Roles are CenterReferee and AssistantReferee, right? Or is there any distinction between AssistantReferee1 and AssistantReferee2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you won't achieve what you are trying to using `has_many`. At least not the way your table is designed. You should try using `scope` instead, unfortunately.

---

On the other hand, there is a different way to design your system. See the new `Assignment`. Schema:

```rb
create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "game_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
end
```

Models:

```rb
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :games, through: :assignments
end

class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
end
```

You may wanna differ a `center referee` from an `assistant referee`.

I don't know exactly what your `role` column at the `User` model means, so I will assume your  `role` column has nothing to do with center/assistant referee.

If this is the case, I'd add an unsigned tinyint `role` to `Assignment` and use it as enum. So my model would be:

```rb
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :user

  enum role: { center_referee: 0, assistant_referee_1: 1, assistant_referee_2: 2 }

  # in case there must be only a kind of referee for a game:
  validates(:role, uniqueness: { scope: [:game_id] })
end
```

And my Schema:

```rb
create_table "assignments", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "role", limit: 1, unsigned: true
  t.integer "game_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
end
```

Comment: I've asked how to model these before for what I'm trying to achieve and to no real avail. In my app there will be a League who initially creates Games. When a game is created, an assignment to go along with that game is also created. The assignment just holds the data for which Users(center_referee, assistant_referee_1 & 2) are on that particular Game. My User model also contains `ROLES = %w[admin assignor referee]` for the different roles a User can have in this app. An Assignor assigns referees to a game via the assignment to that game. I hope that clears some stuff up.

Comment: The problem is that there is no Rails-way to handle the queries you are trying to make just using associations and you may need to try another approaches. One of them is the suggested above, which redesigns your tables a little bit, but keep its purpose (using an intermediate table as many-to-many relation). The other one is making these queries yourself. If you wish not to change your table, how do you feel about adding a `users` method to your Assignment? `def users User.where(id: [center_referee_id, assistant_referee_id_1, assistant_referee_id_2])`

Comment: Your solution uses more than one foreign key to the users table and Rails has no way to handle it by itself. Creating this `users` method will let you use like: `game.assignment.users`. You can create a `users` method in your `Game` model too: `def users assignment.users end`. Anyway, if this feels good for you, just let me know and I'll edit my answer. Otherwise, I can try suggesting yet another approach

Comment: I made a dummy app to test your schema above and it works perfectly. It's what I need in the end. I really like the way you implemented the role feature as well. I think I know how to implement what I need to from here on. If I have other questions do you mind if I reach out to you?

Comment: @wayoh22 feel free to contact me at any time. I've added my Linkedin link to my profile

Comment: João, how would I go about having all 3 assignment forms in one view?

Comment: That's a though question because I am a 100% backend dev. I've written very few views so far. But maybe this can help you: https://meaganwaller.com/use-a-nested-dynamic-form-with-a-hasmany-through-association-in-rails

Comment: That article was exactly what I needed, thanks!